What would happen if the voltage dropped below one volt and the button was not hit?
At the Trinity test site, Robert Oppenheimer is instructing Bainbridge,
who is operating a kill switch:

Robert: Watch that needle. If the detonators don't charge or the voltage drops
below one volt, you hit that button, you abort.

What would happen if the voltage dropped below one volt and the button was not hit?

If the detonators don't fire in the correct sequence or there is insufficient voltage to fire them all, instead of creating an implosion, there will simply be an explosion.
The material inside the 'shell' will be blown apart at great force, turning the metal into dust which will then be caught by the wind.

KISTIAKOWSKY: I can’t. I just know the implosion lenses will work.
OPPENHEIMER: If we fire those detonators and  they don’t trigger the reaction, two years’ worth of plutonium will  be scattered across white sand
Oppenheimer - Screenplay


I.E., it will explode conventionally, but there will be no significant contribution from atomic fission. I believe that this is called a "squib" explosion.

@RBarryYoung It's a fizzle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizzle_(nuclear_explosion)

@MontyWild a non-fissile fizzle :-)

@MontyWild - If it blows the side off the bomb without creating a critical mass, it would just be a squib, not a fizzle
